# Does Apache Kafka run on Open JDK

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to find out the following:

1. Can Apache Kafka run on OpenJDK
2. What are the requirements for installation
3. What are the differences between

Using OracleJDK, I know it works on my machine 
[Setting Up and Running Apache Kafka on Windows OS](https://dzone.com/articles/running-apache-kafka-on-windows-os)

Comment: Thanks to the answers below, I can confirm that I have managed to run the OpenJDK with Apache Kafka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. According to [Kafka Docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#java),

> From a security perspective, we recommend you use the latest released
>   version of JDK 1.8 as older freely available versions have disclosed
>   security vulnerabilities. LinkedIn is currently running JDK 1.8 u5
>   (looking to upgrade to a newer version) with the G1 collector.

2. Hardware and OS requirements:

> You need sufficient memory to buffer active readers and writers. You
>   can do a back-of-the-envelope estimate of memory needs by assuming you
>   want to be able to buffer for 30 seconds and compute your memory need
>   as write_throughput*30.
>
> The disk throughput is important. We have 8x7200 rpm SATA drives. In
>   general disk throughput is the performance bottleneck, and more disks
>   is better. Depending on how you configure flush behavior you may or
>   may not benefit from more expensive disks (if you force flush often
>   then higher RPM SAS drives may be better).

> Kafka should run well on any unix system and has been tested on Linux
>   and Solaris. We have seen a few issues running on Windows and Windows
>   is not currently a well supported platform though we would be happy to
>   change that.

3. OpenJDK is a free and open-source implementation of the Java SE Platform Edition. There are no major technical differences between OpenJDK and OracleJDK however, you should note that Oracle will deliver releases every 3 years with long term support, while OpenJDK will be released every six months and will only support the newest release available.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_system_requirements.html should indicate similar requirements to the current version of openjdk.
3. OpenJDK is an open source version of the JDK. Oracle's JDK is not open source and requires a license for non personal use. There isn't any large technical difference between the two. Oracle's JDK builds from OpenJDK.